# Safari Put Request Method not allowed cors issue

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, safari, cors, put

I am making a put request from safari which is giving CORS issue i.e

```
Failed to load resource: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
```

But it is working fine in chrome, you can see my response header and please help me if i am working something wrong

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With ,allow-access");
```

Answer (score 1):

I just replace `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");` with `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT");` and it's working fine, still have a doubt what is the problem with the '*'.

Comment: even i did this res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*,PUT"); and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Turns out server had Access-Control-Allow-Methods response header's value is set to *. It had to explicitly set to allow methods instead of a wildcard as it is not supported by a safari in iOS as given here in this MDN doc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods